# very weird arithmetic output with R

Tags: r, sum

It is a bit embarrassing to ask this question, but I don't know how to make sense of this. While doing something else, I ran this calculation in R:

```
(-3/5*2) + (2/5*3)
[1] 2.220446e-16
```

The output should actually be **0**, so I don't understand where R's output came from. I tried restarting R and expressing this calculation in different ways (e.g. with decimals instead of fractions). Also, if I replace the second term, now R gives me the expected output:

```
(-3/5*2) + 6/5
[1] 0
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: This has to do with the way a computer handles [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).  You can check things like this for equality using `all.equal((-3/5*2) + (2/5*3), 0)`

Comment: As Justin pointed out, your problem is with issues that arise in performing arithmetic on computers using numbers in floating-point representation. But note that the number reported by R may not be zero, it is damn close to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing those results because in general, computer arithmetic with floating point numbers is not exact (not just in R). 2.220446e-16 is *essentially* 0.

Here's a helpful pdf on this, specifically for R:
https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~stat782/downloads/04-Numerics.pdf

Comment: everytime you see e-16 that's basically called "machine epsilon".